# How to multiply a column of queryset by a constant in Django?

Tags: django

I need to multiply the third column of a queryset by a constant number. How to do this?

e.g.

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(product_id=2).order_by('component')
```

This has three columns. Third Column is an integer. I need to multiply by a constant say ( pi = 3.14). How to do this? I need to return the new queryset to Django template.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add new method in Queryset , have a look into:

http://adam.gomaa.us/blog/2009/feb/16/subclassing-django-querysets/index.html

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/